# Set input var of SQL stored procedure depending on it's value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm wanting to set a stored procedure input parameter to either a static int value or one generated from a sub-query depending on it's string value.

So basically I have this at the start of my stored procedure; after which is a regular INSERT query to create a new product.

```
IF @typeName = 'Unassigned'
BEGIN
    SET @typeName = 0;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @typeName = (SELECT type.id FROM shared.prod_type type
    WHERE type.name = typeName COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci);
END
```

This is just giving me an error in phpMyAdmin saying my syntax is wrong but with no indication of which part.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What is the syntax error?  It should be pointing to a line in the code.

Comment: It just does a big error dump showing the full query and saying `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN SET @typeName = 0; END ELSE BEGIN SET @typeName = (SELECT typ' at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

This query is suspicious:

```
SELECT type.id
FROM shared.prod_type type
WHERE type.name = typeName COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

It might work if you have a column or variable called `typeName`.  But this is probably what you want:

```
SELECT type.id
FROM shared.prod_type type
WHERE type.name = @typeName COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: So I have form where a user can either choose from already existing product types or create their own on the fly when creating a new product. So if the product is flagged with a new product type it will create that type in a new table before creating the product; therefore the id of that type is unknown therefore I need the subquery to return an id of a product based on a name. 'Unassigned' isn't stored in the DB  as it is just arbitrary term; if it is 'Unassigned; I want the value of the var to be 0

Comment: So type.name = typeName is referring to the string value of the original parameter not to the modified var